# spring jar bootRun causes GraphQL Schema error

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, executable-jar, graphql-java

When I build my Spring Boot application using gradle `bootRun` or `build` and then run the output jar, I get the following enormous list of errors out of the console log.

---

```
2018-03-18 00:49:38.754 ERROR 228 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at edu.ycp.cs482.iorcapi.IorcApiApplication$Companion.main(IorcApiApplication.kt:24) [classes!/:na]
    at edu.ycp.cs482.iorcapi.IorcApiApplication.main(IorcApiApplication.kt) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [api-iorc-0.0.1-dev.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [api-iorc-0.0.1-dev.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [api-iorc-0.0.1-dev.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [api-iorc-0.0.1-dev.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServlet' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema]: Factory method 'graphQLSchema' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:234) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:215) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:79) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServlet' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema]: Factory method 'graphQLSchema' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema]: Factory method 'graphQLSchema' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema]: Factory method 'graphQLSchema' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema]: Factory method 'graphQLSchema' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule.setupModule(KotlinModule.kt:44) ~[jackson-module-kotlin-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:747) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt.registerKotlinModule(Extensions.kt:16) ~[jackson-module-kotlin-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolver.createDataFetcher(MethodFieldResolver.kt:42) ~[graphql-java-tools-4.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser$createObject$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.apply(SchemaParser.kt:124) ~[graphql-java-tools-4.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser$createObject$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.apply(SchemaParser.kt:46) ~[graphql-java-tools-4.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at graphql.schema.GraphQLObjectType$Builder.field(GraphQLObjectType.java:163) ~[graphql-java-6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.createObject(SchemaParser.kt:122) ~[graphql-java-tools-4.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.parseSchemaObjects(SchemaParser.kt:83) ~[graphql-java-tools-4.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.makeExecutableSchema(SchemaParser.kt:107) ~[graphql-java-tools-4.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.graphQLSchema(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:87) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-4.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$db6a5aef.CGLIB$graphQLSchema$0(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-4.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$db6a5aef$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8d6cdbae.invoke(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-4.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$db6a5aef.graphQLSchema(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-4.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[api-iorc-0.0.1-dev.jar:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

Based on some testing with my classpath, this may be due to the graphQlSchema parser not finding my schema file within the classpath. However, I do know that the schema file does make it into the jar and is stored correctly in the projects resources folder. Furthermore, the build works correctly if I run it within Intelij. I'd eventually like to deploy this application in a docker file so this issue is holding that back.

my gradle buildscript is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.21'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
        gradleDockerVersion = '1.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")

        classpath("se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:${gradleDockerVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'

group = 'edu.ycp.cs482'
version = '0.0.1-dev'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}


jar {
    baseName = "api-iorc"
    group    = "edu.ycp.cs482.iorcapi"
    version  = "0.0.1-dev"
    manifest { attributes "Main-Class": "edu.ycp.cs482.IorcApiApplication" }
}

docker {


//  runCommand "apt-get update"

}

task buildDocker(type: Docker) {
    applicationName = "iorc-api"
    baseImage "frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim"
    maintainer 'xxxxxxx "xxxxxx@ycp.edu"'
    push = project.hasProperty('push')
    tag = 'testbuild'
    addFile {
        from jar
        rename {'app.jar'}
    }
    entryPoint(['java', '-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom', '-jar', '/app.jar'])
    // exposePort(8080)
}

buildDocker.dependsOn(build)

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springBootAdminVersion = '1.5.7'
    springCloudVersion = 'Edgware.SR1'
}

dependencies {

    compile('com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:4.0.0')

    compile('com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:4.0.0')
    compile('com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:4.3.0')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
    compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client')
    compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-server')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.retry:spring-retry')
    //compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    //testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')

    compile('com.mmnaseri.utils:spring-data-mock:1.1.4')

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-dependencies:${springBootAdminVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

[If you need more information the public repository is here](https://github.com/YoungMaker/iORC-API)

Comment: The root error is `ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.KotlinReflectionInternalError` so somehow somewhere that Kotlin class is needed and you don't have it on the classpath. No clue how or why, though... Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out that the fasterxml jackson module version didn't agree with my projects setup, as seen here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/97

adding this line to the gradle.build file under the dependencies block solved the issue

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.2")
```

Thanks to [kaqqao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294657/kaqqao) for his comment, it was with this information that I was able to google the *right* error in the very large stack trace.